# Do colour space models form vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

My reasoning: we can take as base sRGB, HSL, etc. colorspaces.
The underlying field can be the real numbers.

However, if you multiply a color for a negative number, our “vector” would have negative values, and negative values of R,G or B don’t make so much sense.
Hence, I would be tempted to say that they form a convex cone rather than a vector space but, and I may be wrong, we can actually subtract colors and therefore restricting R to R+ would prevent me to model an important operation you can do on colors: subtract them.

But there is also another point: in reality you cannot use all the real numbers but a subset of them which maybe the interval [0,1] (which I don’t know if it’s a field) or the subset {0, 1, 2, .., 255} of the Natural numbers but I don’t know if it is a field either.

At the same time, I could just say that colors form a vector space but in practice I am only using the first quadrant and only the interval [0,1] or the subset {0,1,2,…,255} of the underlying field. Would that reasoning stand up?

Finally, what are other structures that would suit colors modeling?

Comment: In RGB notation colours are just a finite set of three numbers from 0 to 255. I don't think it is worthwhile thinking about that set much more than that

Comment: I guess another type of color modeling is that in $\mathbb{C}$, a pretty way to illustrate 2D functions is by associating each point in the output space with a color. Specifically, you can use hues to correspond to the direction away from $(0,0)$, and you can use shading to correspond to the distance away from $(0,0)$. It's typically called "domain coloring", and 3Blue1Brown talks about it in a [video here](https://youtu.be/b7FxPsqfkOY?si=GdNEit_kKmXmC-yR).

Comment: I guess you could consider them a $\mathbb{Z}/256\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: @RichardJensen Is that a field?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{Z}/256\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring, and a "vector space over a ring" is called a module, checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)

Comment: With prime p, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ becomes a field.

Comment: Here are some references that might interest you, concerning algebras of colors: https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1072&context=modvis#:~:text=A%20color%20algebra%20refers%20to,the%20basis%20of%20sensory%20data. and https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/LA/system/media_files/binaries/248/original/The_%E2%80%98algebra%E2%80%99_of_color%CE%BBv3.pdf?1444253494 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnUYoQ1pwes and you can find more by searching for *algebra of colors*.

Comment: Colorspace is not closed under addition. For example $(200,200,200)$ can't be added to itself to obtain a valid color. So if you're going to try and define it you'll need a non-standard addition.

Comment: I advise you to take a look at the very interesting recent book by Mathieu Hébert "Optical Models for Material Appearance" Science Press, EDP Sciences ISBN 978-2-7598-2647-6

Comment: @RichardJensen Cool! But as someone pointed out, with prime p, ℤ/ℤ becomes a field and the closest prime to 256 is 257, so we could consider ℤ/257ℤ instead to fix the field issue? In that case it looks like that we would have a vector space, no? EDIT: according to chat GTP yes, but I wish an answer from a more reliable source! :D Or even better, to consider Z/251Z so we can still use 8-bits representation :D

Comment: I think you have to turn to a logarithmic approach as given by "Color LIP model" [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780123859839000028) developed by M. Jourlin.

Comment: Just to note: "Colors" in the sense of (human) vision and "color space models" are not the same thing. Since it sounds as if your interest is in some three-numerical-component model of color (which among other matters originates with approximating biological features of the human retina), it might be worth editing the title and question to specify this.

Comment: Yes, ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$ is a field when $p$ is a prime, but fields (and vector spaces) have properties that, if I'm not mistaken, make no sense for colors. For example, each element $x$ in a field (also in a vector space) has an additive inverse, an element you can add to $x$ to get zero. What would it mean to add two colors together – say, two shades of red – to get no color?

Comment: See the discussion of cones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space#History).

Comment: @J.G. As I wrote, I thought about convex cones (which, on the other hand, is very popular) but they won't capture color subtraction, which is a legit operation on colours.

Comment: Fair enough. The truth is no one mathematical notion, its name ending in _space_ or otherwise, captures all types of colour space.